# Java: Why can't I declare integer types using scientific notation?

Tags: java, integer, long-integer, scientific-notation, exponent

I can easily read `2e15` as "two quadrillion" at a glance, but for `2000000000000000` I have to count the zeroes, which takes longer and can lead to errors.

Why can't I declare an `int` or `long` using a literal such as `2e9` or `1.3e6`? I understand that a negative power of 10, such as `2e-3`, or a power of 10 that is less than the number of decimal places, such as `1.0003e3`, would produce a floating point number, but why doesn't Java allow such declarations, and simply truncate the floating-point part and issue a mild warning in cases where the resulting value is non-integral?

Is there a technical reason why this is a bad idea, or is this all about type-safety? Wouldn't it be trivial for the compiler to simply parse a statement like

`long x = 2e12` as `long x = 2000000000000 //OK for long`

and `int y = 2.1234e3` as `int y = 2123.4 //warning: loss of precision`

Comment: [Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/04/03/10251901.aspx): "I'm often asked why the compiler does not implement this feature or that feature, and of course the answer is always the same: **because no one implemented it.** Features start off as unimplemented and only become implemented when people spend effort implementing them: no effort, no feature. This is an unsatisfying answer of course, because usually the person asking the question has made the assumption that the feature is so obviously good that we need to have had a reason to **not** implement it."

Comment: @BrianRoach: I know what an integer is. I was asking if there's a specific reason as to why numbers that are expressed in floating-point form but evaluate to an **integral** value ex: `2.3e3 == 2300` can't be assigned without an explicit cast. 

Maybe the reason is simply what John Kugelman quoted. That would make sense. The reason I asked is just that I was curious if there was a technical reason why such a feature would be a bad idea.

Comment: No, I get the first part ... but that's not your second example; `int y = 2123.4`

Comment: @BrianRoach In my second example I was suggesting that the compiler would issue a warning for a non-integral expression using scientific notation being assigned to an integer, in contrast to the first example, in which the expression is determined to be an integral value and can therefore be assigned to an integer type without any loss of precision. I understand that Java does not allow such assignments without an explicit cast; I was merely curious about the design decisions involved.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's because when you use the scientific notation you create [a floating point number](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2) (a double in your example). And you can't assign a floating point to an integer (that would be a narrowing primitive conversion, [which is not a valid assignment conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2)).

So this would not work either for example:

```
int y = 2d; //can't convert double to int
```

You have a few options:

- explicitly cast the floating point to an integer:  `int y = (int) 2e6;`
- with Java 7+ use a thousand separator: `int y = 2_000_000;`

Comment: The options you mention are easy to use and remove any need for the hypothetical feature I was talking about. Thanks!

Comment: @assylias Yes but a number without a radix point and without a `d` or `f` suffix is assumed to be an `int`. So I think the OP was asking why, for example, wouldn't `2e8` be interpreted as an `int`, and why wouldn't `2e12l` be interpreted as a `long` (which would be consistent with how non-scientific notation numbers are interpreted). So the answer seems to be "There's no technical reason why the Java compiler designers handled sci notation in this regard. They could have done things the way the OP suggested, but they didn't--perhaps they just didn't think of doing it that way."

Comment: @yroc well yes - I just pointed to the relevant parts of the specification that  say that it doesn't work. Why it was done that way has to be asked to the JDK developers. See also the first comment under the question.

Answer (score 2):

Because it's a shortcoming of Java.

(Specifically, there is clearly a set of literals represented by scientific notation that are exactly represented by ints and longs, and it is reasonable to desire a way to express those literals as ints and longs. But, in Java there isn't a way to do that because all scientific notation literals are necessarily floats because of Java's language definition.)

Answer (score 1):

You are asking about the rules on writing a integer **literals**. See this reference:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html
The capability to use scientific notation as an integer literal might make things easier indeed but has not been implemented. I do not see any technical reason that would prevent such a feature from being implemented.